# Выполнение командной строки после компиляции

Tags: visual-c++, отладка

Компилирую dll в Visual c++ 2015, делаю сборку затем запускаю другое приложение чтобы подключить dll. Можно настроить проект чтобы "запуск без отладки" запускал это самое другое приложение куда подключается dll?

Comment: Прописать в свойствах отладки команду на запуск нужного приложения пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прописать в свойствах отладки отлаживаемой DLL команду на запуск требующегося приложения.